# django inheritence admin site -- why do charfields follow down the tree automatically whereas fields that are defined classes do not?

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.6

django inheritence admin site -- why do charfields follow down the tree automatically whereas fields that are defined classes do not?  I've been searching for the answer for several hours and this is my first question so please be gentle.

here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.db.models import EmailField


class XObj(models.Model):
    auto_increment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.creation_date.datetime)

    def date_created(self):
        return self.creation_date

    def date_last_change(self):
        return str(self.auto_increment_id)


class Address(XObj):
    # todo: differentiate between US and non US addresses and validate
    house = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    street2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.house, self.street, self.street2, self.city, self.state, self.zipcode, self.country)


class Entity(XObj):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    # todo: validate email
    email = EmailField()

    # def _init_(self):
    #     self.full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    #
    def __str__(self):
        return "Entity"


class Person(Entity):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    address = Address

    # def _init_(self):
    #     self.first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

class Vendor(XObj):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    address = Address
    website = models.URLField
    point_of_contact = Person

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Hotel(Vendor):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Restaurant(Vendor):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Lounge(Vendor):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and here is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person, Address, Entity, Vendor, Hotel, Restaurant, Lounge

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in Address._meta.fields if field.name !="id"]
# TODO: add implementation for non charfields
admin.site.register(Person)
admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
admin.site.register(Entity)
admin.site.register(Vendor)
admin.site.register(Hotel)
admin.site.register(Restaurant)
admin.site.register(Lounge)
```

Here is my add for Person:

[Person Admin Site Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEDaJ.png)

Here is my add for Address:

[Address Admin Site Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLGwL.png)

Why are the address fields not in the Person add admin page?

Please be my Ace of Spades :)

Comment: What are `address = Address` and `point_of_contact = Person` meant to do? Are the fields still missing from the person admin if you remove those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

Your model should be

```
class Person(Entity):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    address = models.ForeignKey(
    'Address',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

Remember do the migration after fix it. Also django has build-in auto_increment_id for every model, you don't have to rewrite it.

Comment: Thank you very much @windsooon!  Made your changes (auto_increment_id too), and a now I'm seeing what I want.  I need to explore this part of the documentation.  I'm coming over from C# where things are a little bit ... different.